# Vue - How to Draw Waveforms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, waveform

I'm looking more for direction rather than code. I wanted to know was there a standard for drawing waveforms in Vue. I do NOT want to draw audio waveforms. I've been searching online and almost every article or site I have found was about audio waveforms, not actually plotting your own X and Y values.
What I would like to do is receive data over a websocket (this is already done) and plot this data into a waveform. Is there a standard for this? I'm pretty new to UI (always been backend but now becoming full stacks) and was sure this type of problem is already solved and don't want to recreate the wheel.

Comment: Drawing a chart is nothing Vue specific - any JS chart lib would be fine. I have successfully used [vue-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs) with websocket data. The package just wraps the chart.js library and exposes the methods to a Vue component. Give that a try?

You then just need to receive the data and save it in your component's `data` function and pass the data as props. Vue's reactivity and chart.js can handle the rest.

Comment: @xenetics Thanks man. I'm relatively new to front end but everything i could find was audio specific. I appreciate it and i wish i could accept your answer for the thread

Comment: I will add it as an answer and you can accept ;) let me know if you need more guidance. I actually had it an answer but changed it to a comment at the last moment, haha. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a chart is nothing Vue specific - any JS chart lib would be fine. I have successfully used [vue-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs) with websocket data. The package just wraps the chart.js library and exposes the methods to a Vue component. Give that a try?

You then just need to receive the data and save it in your component's `data` function and pass the data as props. Vue's reactivity and chart.js can handle the rest.